# flask login_required decorator location - written from scratch

Tags: python, authentication, flask, decorator, blueprint

I started experimenting with flask a while back, I quite like the idea of a minimalistic framework that can be expanded as and when needed. I have limited experience with web frameworks, but I do understand the concept of a framework. I'm running into the following problem (worth mentioning I do **NOT** want to use flask-login, I'm trying to replicate a login system from my working PHP system):

I create a new app using an app factory, loading 2 blueprints in the process. one is auth (login/logout) and one is dashboard (index, main, default page, whatever you want to call it). the login works like a charm, it does exactly what it should do. all I need to do is write a login_required decorator and wrap it around the routes I want to be login only.

this is my code, yet when I try to run it in one of my blueprints, I get this message:

```
AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'login_required'
```

where do I put the decorator for it to be recognised as a "global" component and be accessible from anywhere, mainly from blueprints?

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask

def init():
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)

    app.config.from_object('config.Config')

    def login_required(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            if 'auth' in session:
                return f(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                flash('You need to login first')
                return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))

        return wrap

    with app.app_context():
        from application.auth import auth
        from application.dashboard import dashboard
    
        app.register_blueprint(auth.bp_auth)
        app.register_blueprint(dashboard.bp_dashboard)
    
        return app
```

dashboard.py (this is one of the blueprints)

```
from flask import Blueprint, current_app, redirect, render_template, session, url_for

bp_dashboard = Blueprint('dashboard', __name__)

@bp_dashboard.route('/')
@current_app.login_required # I also tried @app.login_required, @login_required, same error
def index():    
    return render_template('dashboard/index.html')
```

What am I doing wrong? I guess I'm very new to the entire application context concept, but I thought current_app takes care of that.

Answer (score 0):

based on your code above, i guess you are missing `from functools import wraps`

refer to this https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps

to make things more consistent, just move block below to `auth` Blueprint

```
from functools import wraps  # Don't forget this import
[..]

def login_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'auth' in session:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            flash('You need to login first')
            return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))

    return wrap
```

and then in `dashboard` Blueprint import it

```
from flask import Blueprint, current_app, redirect, render_template, session, url_for

from .auth import login_required # here

bp_dashboard = Blueprint('dashboard', __name__)

@bp_dashboard.route('/')
@login_required  # You don't need to prefix it with "bp_dashboard" nor  "current_app"
def index():    
    return render_template('dashboard/index.html')
```

hope this solves your issue.